# Error exporting data to JSON in Business Central

Tags: json, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am trying to export data to Json and having some trouble. When I run this I get error that says: `The JSON object already contains the key 'Description'`.

And the same error comes up with whatever line is run where I'm adding. Here is my code, can anyone see why it is happening...

```
codeunit 14135101 "ExportSalesToJson"
{
    procedure ExportSalesInvoiceAsJson(SalesInvoiceHeader: Record "Sales Invoice Header"; var JsonArr: JsonArray)

    var

        SalesLine: Record "Sales Invoice Line";
        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson: JsonObject;
        SalesLineArray: JsonArray;

        SalesIvoiceLineJson: JsonObject;
        SalesInvoiceLine: Record "Sales Invoice Line";


    begin

        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson.Add(SalesInvoiceHeader.FieldCaption("No."), SalesInvoiceHeader."No.");
        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson.Add(SalesInvoiceHeader.FieldCaption("Document Date"), SalesInvoiceHeader."Document Date");
        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson.Add(SalesInvoiceHeader.FieldCaption("Posting Date"), SalesInvoiceHeader."Posting Date");
        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson.Add(SalesInvoiceHeader.FieldCaption("Posting Description"), SalesInvoiceHeader."Posting Description");


        //SalesInvoiceLine.Reset();
        SalesInvoiceLine.SetRange("Document No.", SalesInvoiceHeader."No.");
        if SalesInvoiceLine.FindSet() then
            repeat

                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption("No."), SalesInvoiceLine."No.");
                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Description), SalesInvoiceLine.Description);
                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Type), Format(SalesInvoiceLine.Type));
                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption("Unit Price"), SalesInvoiceLine."Unit Price");
                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Amount), SalesInvoiceLine.Amount);
                SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Quantity), SalesInvoiceLine.Quantity);
                SalesLineArray.Add(SalesIvoiceLineJson);
            until SalesInvoiceLine.Next() = 0;
        SalesInvoiceHeaderJson.Add('Lines', SalesIvoiceLineJson);
        JsonArr.Add(SalesInvoiceHeaderJson);

    end;



    procedure ExportDocs()
    var
        SalesInvHeader: Record "Sales Invoice Header";
        JsonArr: JsonArray;
        Tempblob: Codeunit "Temp Blob";
        IStream: InStream;
        OStream: OutStream;
        ExportFileName: Text;
    begin
        SalesInvHeader.Reset();
        SalesInvHeader.FindSet();
        repeat
            ExportSalesInvoiceAsJson(SalesInvHeader, JsonArr);
        until SalesInvHeader.Next() = 0;

        Tempblob.CreateOutStream(OStream);

        IF JsonArr.WriteTo(OStream) THEN begin
            ExportFileName := 'Sales Invoices.json';
            Tempblob.CreateInStream(IStream);
            DownloadFromStream(IStream, '', '', '', ExportFileName);
        end;

    end;
```

Tried commenting out (specificly) the `SalesInvoiceHeaderJson` lines, but kept getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing your `SalesIvoiceLineJson` variable without resetting it. This means that when your `repeat` statement runs the second time, the `JsonObject` will already contain the properties you are trying to add.

The best way to fix it would be to move the code within the `repeat` statement to a separate function with a local variable:

```
local procedure AddSalesInvoiceLine(SalesInvoiceLine: Record "Sales Invoice Line"; var SalesInvoiceLineArray: JsonArray)
var
    SalesIvoiceLineJson: JsonObject;
begin
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption("No."), SalesInvoiceLine."No.");
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Description), SalesInvoiceLine.Description);
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Type), Format(SalesInvoiceLine.Type));
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption("Unit Price"), SalesInvoiceLine."Unit Price");
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Amount), SalesInvoiceLine.Amount);
    SalesIvoiceLineJson.Add(SalesInvoiceLine.FieldCaption(Quantity), SalesInvoiceLine.Quantity);
    SalesInvoiceLineArray.Add(SalesIvoiceLineJson);
end;
```

And then call that function from the `repeat` statement.

Another solution would be to clear the `SalesIvoiceLineJson` at the beginning of the repeat statement:

```
Clear(SalesIvoiceLineJson);
```